# What is Double? (C#)

Tags: c#, types, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Today I'm wondering about `Double` in .Net. I've used it with `Int32` the past days and started wondering what the max value is.

The MSDN page for [Double.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx) says `1.7976931348623157E+308`. I'm pretty sure I'm reading that wrong.

How many bytes does `Double` take up (in memory)?
What is the actual maximum number (explain the the E+308)?
Is Double.MaxValue bigger than `UInt32`? Bigger than `UInt64`?
And while we are at it, what is the difference between `Float` and `Double`?

Comment: In order to gain understanding on how the numbers are written, check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: Thanks to everyone who made an effort to answer. To everyone who voted duplicate -- many SO users are shallow as usual. Please take the time to read the question fully before voting. :/

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

Double is 64 bit floating point value and float is a 32 bit.
So double is able to store twice big value as of float.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.71).aspx

Just read the top lines on the links, you'll get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

About `E+308`: though `2^64` is far less that `1e+308`, you must consider that `double` is not "precise" number, it has only a few significant digits (precision), so it does not need to store all ~308 digits. With this logic behind the `double` structure, it can contain numbers up to `e+308` in 64 bits.